# Days and Time Mathematical Expression

Tags: string, time, expression

I have the following code:

`max(seconds+minutes*60+hours*3600-time,0)` however I need it to also count the number of days, would anyone have any advice?

Thanks!

TC

Comment: What programming language are you using? C, java, c++, objective c? Which framework?

Comment: Please add a proper language tag.

Comment: number of days * 24 * 60 * 60 in seconds

Answer (score 1):

Since a day has 86400 seconds:

```
max(seconds+minutes*60+hours*3600+days*86400-time,0)
```

Less messy:

```
max(seconds + (minutes * 60) + (hours * 3600) + (days * 86400) - time, 0)
```

Or: `max(seconds + (minutes * 60) + (hours * 60 * 60) + (days * 60 * 60 * 24) - time, 0)`

Comment: Thanks so much, works very well! May I ask (although this is outside the scope of the original question), do you think there is a way within the code to represent multiple days as # days instead of # hours (e.g at the moment 2 days is represented as 48 hrs)?